# sscanf cycle segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cycle, scanf

I haven't programmed for a couple years and I have a question with `sscanf`:

I want to separate a string into several using `sscanf`, but `sscanf` gives me segmentation fault in a cycle. Why is that? how can I use `sscanf` in a cycle without happening?

Example:

```
int main() {
    char str[100];
    char mat[100][100]; int i = 0;
    strcpy(str, "higuys\nilovestackoverflow\n2234\nhaha");

    while (sscanf(str, "%s", mat[i]) == 1) i++;  
}
```

Comment: change this: `while(sscanf(str,"%s",  mat[i]) == 1);    i++; ` to this: `while(sscanf(str,"%s",  mat[i]) == 1)    i++; `

Comment: @bruceg I don't see how it would be better!

Comment: and don't forget to append a " to the string in the strcpy line.

Comment: There's a typo here. Your code is just an infinite loop. It doesn't/cannot segfault.

Comment: that ; was a misswrite , that woesn't the problem 
y i know , forget the typos, the sscanf still segm faults

Comment: ill just edit it..

Comment: This is why we copy/paste instead of re-entering the source. When you don't provide a [mcve] we are all prevented from helping you solve your problem(s)

Comment: The other main problem is the you keep scanning the same string over and over, and sscanf always returns 1 for you.  Eventually, i will get past 99, and you'll get your segmentation fault.  You probably want to use strtok and not sscanf.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the original code had a stray `;` after the while which means the while loop didn't include the increment statement.

Comment: yes, I saw that, hence my 2-part answer, so I'll have to edit my answer back to the original state, where I mentally skipped the `;` because with it, no segfault.

Comment: `sscanf()` doesn't know whether `mat[i]` is valid, so it will try to write to it even after `i` increases to/above 100 and `mat[i]` goes out of bounds... until it segfaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);

```
while(sscanf(str,"%s",  mat[i]) == 1)  i++;
```

Since `str` is constant in the prototype it *cannot* be changed by `sscanf` (unless `sscanf` is *very* broken :)), so it successfully repeats over and over, returning 1 all the time...
So `i` increases, and at some point you're hitting a memory boundary and the system stops your harmful program.

If you want to read a multi-line string, use a loop with `strtok` for instance, that will go through your string and yield lines.

Note: my previous answer correctly assumed that the previous version question had a typo with an extra `;` in the middle

```
while(sscanf(str,"%s",  mat[i]) == 1);   i++;
```

is always successful since `str` is the input and doesn't change (unlike when you're reading from a file using `fscanf` or `fgets`).

So it was just an infinite loop in that case.

Comment: i'm pretty sure sscanf stops at \n , it could be the program runs for less than 0.1 seconds so i doubt it.

Comment: @MiguelS - then you get the usual refrain - please run this in a debugger to discover what your real problem is.

Comment: @MiguelS: `sscanf` stops at `'\n'`, stores the word `higuys` into the array `mat[i]` and returns `1`. The loop condition is true, `i` gets incremented and the process goes on for the next element of `mat` as the destination with the same source string... every element of `mat` receives the same `higuys` string, and the loop continues, causing a buffer overflow, invoking undefined behavior and ultimately crashing.

Comment: true, i thought it would jump to the next thing after \n, i don't know where did i get that idea, is it fgets or smth that does that? thanks

Comment: `fscanf` does that if there are no spaces in the string (like in your example) or `fgets`, right.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` stops at `\n`, stores the word `higuys` into the array `mat[i]` and returns `1`. The loop condition is true, `i` gets incremented and the process goes on for the next element of `mat` as the destination with the same source string... every element of `mat` receives the same `higuys` string, and the loop continues, causing a buffer overflow, invoking undefined behavior and ultimately crashing.

Here is how to modify your code to make it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *str = "higuys\nilovestackoverflow\n2234\nhaha";
    char mat[100][100];
    int i = 0, n = 0;

    /* parse the multiline string */
    while (sscanf(str, "%s%n", mat[i], &n) == 1) { 
        str += n;
        i++;  
    }
    /* output the array */
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("mat[%d] = %s\n", j, mat[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```